# Subplots for shap.plots.bar() plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, xgboost, shap

I'd like to add the `shap.plots.bar` (https://github.com/slundberg/shap) figure to a subplot. Something like this...

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8,20))
for (X, y) in [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]:
  model = xgboost.XGBRegressor().fit(X, y)
  explainer = shap.Explainer(model, check_additivity=False)
  shap_values = explainer(X, check_additivity=False)
  shap.plots.bar(shap_values, max_display=6, show=False) # ax=ax ?? 
plt.show()
```

However, `ax` is undefined for `shap.plots.bar`, unlike some other plotting methods such as `shap.dependence_plot(..., ax=ax[0, 0], show=False)`. Is there a way to add many bar plots to a subplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/plots/_bar.py), the function does not create it's own figure. So, you can create a figure and then set the desired axis as the current axis using [`plt.sca`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.sca.html).

Here is how you'd do it using the [bar plot sample code from the documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/bar.html).

```py
import xgboost
import shap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = shap.datasets.adult()
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier().fit(X, y)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model, X)
shap_values = explainer(X)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
plt.sca(ax2)
shap.plots.bar(shap_values)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

If you really want to have the `ax` argument, you'll have to edit the source code to add that option.

Comment: They should really add the `ax=` argument, since the sca() trick is more like a hack.

Comment: Add the argument where?